# Is it possible to enable third party sites to embed my webpage that is rendered on client-side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET core razor page that is mostly **rendered client-side** using JavaScript. That means, as soon as the page loads, I call my `render()` function.

The function involves cloning the content of several `<template>` HTML tags as part of its logic. These tags are included in the page itself.

I would like to allow third party sites to embed this page into any of their own webpage that is hosted in any of their own website that I do not control.

My question: Is this possible?

Comment: Would just a standard [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) do the trick for you?

Comment: whenever you use `iframe` do make sure you have proper `x-frame-options` and `content-security-policy` headers. people often (me included) forgot to whitelist sites allowed to embed the website in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, they will just need to embed it as an `iframe`.

Don't set X-Frame-Options. Don't apply CSP.

In your documentation mention that anyone who wants to embed your page as an `iframe` will beed to allow it to get through CSP policies.